# Telegram and Python

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I'v searched almost two days but had not found anything relevant...

Basically every article and post talks about how to use a bot sending message as itself, but how I could send messages as the user?

I will create a GUI using tkinter with a `entry` and a `button`, where the `button command` function will send the entry as a message of the user.

I know that I can automate it using selenium, but there's any best solution?

Comment: Isn't this precisely what TDlib is for? https://core.telegram.org/tdlib They even have that exact example in their Python library: https://github.com/alexander-akhmetov/python-telegram/blob/master/examples/send_message.py

Comment: Thanks, I'm new with python and did not figured out that tdlib was for that, sorry...